# Incomplete or corrupt PNG file react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-pdf

I am having problems adding an image to my PDF using the react-pdf library https://react-pdf.org.

I keep getting the error:

`Incomplete or corrupt PNG file`

The image displays fine in other parts of my app so I know the base64 that is generated is ok.

I am using

```
<Image
    src={`data:image/png;base64,${base64ResourceFile.Base64}`}
/>
```

I can see by console logging that the correct base64 value is being returned from the API I'm pulling the image from with:

```
const resourceFiles = async ({ data = [], identityAccessKey, resourceID }) => {
  const resourceFilesWithBase64 = await Promise.all(
    data.map(async (file) => {
      const response = await fetch('/api/getIdentityResourceFileById', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ fileID: file?.id, identityAccessKey, resourceID })
      });
      const fileContent = await response.json();
      return {base64: fileContent?.base64};
    })
  );
  return resourceFilesWithBase64;
};

export default resourceFiles;
```

I then use the above method before passing the base64 into the component that uses the `<Image>` component from `react-pdf`

```
const base64ResourceFile = await resourceFiles({
            data: resource_files,
            identityAccessKey: dataVerification?.idv?.data[0]?.idvKey,
            resourceID: id
}).catch(console.error);

<Image
    src={`data:image/png;base64,${base64ResourceFile.base64}`}
/>
```

The error seems to be in `fetchimage.js`

[image]

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: The PNG returned from the API is 500kb, is there a way around the size issue?